# javascript event too slow

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, canvas

Is there any way to improve the following html5 example, or is the browser
just to slow in handling mouse events?
Its a grid, and on the point you move the mouse to you see a red rectangle..
But this rectangle is a kind of lagging behind the mouse, so moving to slow to its position.
(if the mouse is moved pretty fast)

http://jsfiddle.net/191rmac8/

Here the code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">error or not supported.</canvas>
    <script>
        var lineSize = 10;
        var rasterSize = 5;
        var bx = 0;
        var by = 0;

        g2d = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        g2d.setFillColor("rgb(10, 10, 10)");
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, g2d.canvas.width, g2d.canvas.height);
        g2d.setStrokeColor("rgb(0, 0, 255)");
        g2d.setLineWidth(lineSize);

        function repaint(){
            g2d.clearRect(0, 0, g2d.canvas.width, g2d.canvas.height);
            g2d.beginPath();
            for(i = 0; i < rasterSize + 1; i++){
                g2d.moveTo(0, (lineSize / 2) + i * (g2d.canvas.height - lineSize) / (rasterSize));
                g2d.lineTo(g2d.canvas.width, (lineSize / 2) + i * (g2d.canvas.height - lineSize) / (rasterSize)); 
                g2d.moveTo((lineSize / 2) + i * (g2d.canvas.width - lineSize) / (rasterSize), 0);
                g2d.lineTo((lineSize / 2) + i * (g2d.canvas.width - lineSize) / (rasterSize), g2d.canvas.height);
            }
            g2d.stroke();
            g2d.setFillColor("red");
            g2d.fillRect(bx - 5, by - 5, 11, 11);
        }
        repaint();

        g2d.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
            bx = e.offsetX;
            by = e.offsetY;
            repaint();
        });
    </script>
</body>

body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: black;
}
canvas {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The mouse will always be drawn faster than anything in the browser so no matter what you do there will still be a lag

Comment: It's not the mouse event that's being handled poorly, it's the fact that `mousemove` is one of those "called a whole lot in a very short amount of time" kind of events. This means `repaint` is called a *lot* every second, so you would need to optimize that function to see a performance improvement.

Comment: You could always just put `cursor: none` in the canvas css to hide the mouse, it will make the delay less perceptive

Comment: What about instead of checking for `mousemove` and repainting whenever  it moves you just set a timeout loop and repaint the mouse every 100ms or 1ms or whatever looks good?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the mouse events from the drawing to increase performance.

- Create an array to hold mouse points
- In mousemove, push the current mouse position into the array.
- Depending on your design, you might use Aboca's idea of capping the capture rate of the points.
- Create a loop using requestAnimationFrame.
- In the loop, draw all points since the loop was last executed as 1 path.

The benefits are:

- requestAnimationFrame is efficient at drawing.
- You are drawing a polyline through a batch of points instead of 1 point at a time.
- Changing context state is somewhat expensive, and this lets you change state only once.

Answer (score -1):

You can cap the rate of the repaint like I did here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sh6o91g4/1/

Adjust as you see fit as it will fasten the perfomance but it will reduce the quality of the rendering too (skipping frames has it's drawbacks)

```
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            if(now - time > 10){
                time = now;
                bx = e.offsetX;
                by = e.offsetY;
                repaint();
            }
```